# How would i inject a partial view on a toggle button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap admin theme which is using a checkbox style toggle what I want to be able to do uppon this toggle being pressed to on. I want to load a partial view of more address ie there partner information into the screen. What is my best approach in doing this. I am using mvc 5 and c# btw.

I am used to webforms so forgive me if this basic question annoys people usually i would have created a panel and loaded the controls inside that how is the same done in mvc world ?

```
<section class="col col-3">
  <label class="toggle">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-toggle" checked>
      <i></i>Is this a Joint Application
      </label>
</section>
```

[image]

**Edit 1**

I have tried the above method but as of yet its not loading the element in there is no error in the render of the jquery either

I used a div to store my element but to no avaial.

```
 [HttpGet]
 public PartialViewResult GetPartialView()
 {
    //Add model if any and send it through partialview
    return PartialView("_PartnerNameDetails");
 }
```

And i used the following element to store in

```
<div id="element"></div>
```

**Edit 2** 
So I do a bit more investgating in my jquery its gets to before the selector for the check box but not after it as if tis not firing the change event help plz

```
(function ($) {
   "use strict";
   $(document).ready(function () {    

  inbox();
    $('input[name="checkbox-toggle"]').on('change', function () {
        console.info("I got here ok");


        if (this.checked) {

            //loading partial view
            $('#element').load('/Controller/GetPartialView', function () {
                alert("Partial View Loaded");
            });
        }
        else
            $("#element").html(''); //clearing the innerHTML if checkbox is unchecked
    });
```

**Edit 3**

So I have got a bit futher with this and still no dice I should state I am using a partial view within a shared view using @RenderBody But the page refused to load and I dont see the messagebox on the page.

```
$('#joint input[type="checkbox"]')).on('change', function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            //loading partial view
            $('#element').load('/FormsController/GetPartialView', function () {
                alert("Partial View Loaded");
            });
        }
        else
            $("#element").html(''); //clearing the innerHTML if checkbox is unchecked
    });
```

New html markup with the help of Guru below

```
<section id="joint" class="col col-3">
  <label class="toggle">
      <input type="checkbox" id="chkisJointApplication" name="chkisJointApplication">
         <i></i>Is this a Joint Application
  </label>
</section>
```

Html of MainLayout File with @RenderBody command

```
<!-- Widget Row Start grid -->
<div class="row" id="powerwidgets">
   <div class="col-md-12 bootstrap-grid">
      <div class="panel-body">@RenderBody() </div>
                   <!-- End Widget -->
      </div>
   <!-- /Inner Row Col-md-12 -->
   </div>
<!-- /Widgets Row End Grid-->
```

**Note 1**
Well finally after all that I have the messagebox appearing but no partiaview is being rendered

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult GetPartialView()
{
        //Add model if any and send it through partialview
        return PartialView("_PartnetNameDetails");
 }
 <div id="partnerForm"></div>
```

**Edit 4**
This is the following partial file which i am using above.

```
     <div class="row">

      <section class="col col-6">

        <label class="input">

            <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-user"></i>
            <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name">
        </label>
    </section>
    <section class="col col-6">
        <label class="input">
            <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-user"></i>
            <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last name">
        </label>
    </section>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <section class="col col-6">
        <label class="input">
            <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-envelope"></i>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
        </label>
    </section>
    <section class="col col-6">
        <label class="input">
            <i class="icon-prepend fa fa-phone"></i>
            <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
        </label>
    </section>
      </div>
```

**Edit 5** 
I have changed to this method of using ajax to load the query but now i am getting a 404 not found error

> GET XHR http://localhost:50093/FormsController/GetPartialView [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 43ms]

[image]

```
    $(document).on('change', '#chkisJointApplication', function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetPartialView", "FormsController")',
                type: "Get",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#partnerForm").html(data);
                }
            });

        }
        else
            $("#partnerForm").html(''); //clearing the innerHTML if checkbox is unchecked
    });
```

Screen to show correct partial view name

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a `change event` to your `checkbox` and possibly call the `partialview` through `ajax/load` and append it to your `col-3` `section`. Below is just a sample how you could achieve it.

```
$('input[name="checkbox-toggle"]').on('change',function(){
    if(this.checked)
    { 
       //loading partial view
       $('#element').load('/Controller/GetPartialView',function(){
              alert("Partial View Loaded");
       });
    }
    else
       $("#element").html(''); //clearing the innerHTML if checkbox is unchecked
});
```

In your controller add below `PartialViewResult` Method.

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult GetPartialView()
{
     //Add model if any and send it through partialview
     return PartialView("_PartialViewName");
}
```

**Note -** `#element` is the `id` of the `DOM element` on which you want to load the `partialview`

**Personal Suggestion**

---

Its better to load `partialview` on initial load so that it wont be requested `everytime` or if you are following above approach instead of clearing it on `else` part just `hide` it and when it satisfies `checked` condition, see whether `partialview` is already present, if yes, show the `partialview` else make the ajax call to get the `partialview`

**Edit - 1**

---

Attach it to the `document` to delegate the `event`

```
$(document).on('change','#chkisJointApplication',function(){
    if(this.checked)
    { 
       //loading partial view
       $('#element').load('/Controller/GetPartialView',function(){
              alert("Partial View Loaded");
       });
    }
    else
       $("#element").html(''); //clearing the innerHTML if checkbox is unchecked
})
```

Comment: with this method will all the fields be avaiable to me once i submit them ?.

Comment: You have to bind them to `model` and that's what I mentioned you to pass with the `partialview`

Comment: Have a look at my edit please its  not working but my jquery is not throwing an error weird

Comment: there are no errors being created its not firing the jquery as did a test debug but yet rest of jquery in file is fine

Comment: @yoda77ni.. Does your view which contains `checkbox` load through `ajax`?

Comment: no its just a normal view which is isntiaiated as normal html

Comment: Like using `RenderBody()`

Comment: Yes  Correct using a shared view.

Comment: Try attaching event like this `$('input[type="checkbox"]')` instead of `$('input[name="checkbox-toggle"]')`

Comment: but then would that not go through ever checkbox I only want this to happen for a specific one as per screenshot ?.

Comment: Give an id to its parent `section` and then you can do it like this `$('#parentsectionid input[type="checkbox"]')`

Comment: Ok.. This should definitely work, if it is the partial view being loaded.. `$(document).on('change','#chkisJointApplication',function(){})` instead of `$('input[name="checkbox-toggle"]').on('change',function(){})`

Comment: Can u edit your oginal answer as getting a little bit lost in comments here thanks

Comment: Please see note one we have got it but the partial view aint rendering even though I have form controls inside it for testing :-(

Comment: Does that `partialview` exists in shared folder ?

Comment: No it exists in the Views/Forms Folder ah so all partial views must exist in shared i gather then I move it to shared but stil no dice :-(

Comment: Nothing like that.. You can just try invoking it in web browser copying absolute URL of partial view and see whether you are getting that partial view

Comment: We are at lest getting the message box but the partial view is not rendering i added it to the question

Comment: Its is not finding the `partialview`.. Just place the debugger in `return PartialView` and check if it is hitting the `actionresult` on first instance.. If it is hitting, `partialView` is not found.. Show me your `partialview` too.,.